# Errors when using the Frama-Clang plugin

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, frama-c

Given that the plugin https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html is considered in the "early stages" of development, perhaps I'm out of luck for now. But wondering if anyone else has run into a problem like this:

```
navarre@navarre-t400:~/code/c$ frama-c max.cpp
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing max.cpp (external front-end)
: CommandLine Error: Option 'asm-macro-max-nesting-depth' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
[kernel] user error: Failed to parse C++ file. See Clang messages for more information
[kernel] user error: stopping on file "max.cpp" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

For the record, the contents of max.cpp is as follows:

```
int s(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Even just pointing me toward the mysterious "Clang messages" that the error output suggests I see!

EDIT: I should probably add I'm on Ubuntu and had quite a time getting the build to work, apparently due to a conflict in clang 3.9 in Ubuntu's repos vs a PPA. I eventually got the plugin to build, and now I'm stuck here.

EDIT2: I was able to edit the source code of frama_Clang_register.ml to see the command that is being run. It's this one:

```
framaCIRGen  -target i386-unknown-linux-gnu -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -std=c++11 -nostdinc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++ -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/libc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c --stop-annot-error
```

And so now the question becomes "what is wrong with 'framaCIRGen'. First I noticed I get the offending error even if I just run framaCIRGen and nothing else. Interesting.

And then I notice that the offending thing is (asm-macro-max-nesting-depth) is not present in the source file for framaCIRGen, but *is* in the compiled binary!

It's also not in the output of cpp, so it must have gotten in via a linked library?

```
navarre@navarre-t400:~/Downloads/frama-clang-0.0.3$ cpp -std=c++11 ./FramaCIRGen.cpp -I/usr/lib/llvm-4.0/include   -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -fPIC -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS | grep asm-macro-max-nesting-depth | wc
      0       0       0
```

EDIT:

Here's the output from ./configure:

```
checking for frama-c-gui... no
checking for Makefile.config.in... yes
frama_clang... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for camlp4o... yes
checking for clang... no
checking for clang-3.8... no
checking for clang-3.9... no
checking for clang-4.0... clang-4.0
checking for clang++... no
checking for clang++-3.8... no
checking for clang++-3.9... no
checking for clang++-4.0... clang++-4.0
checking for llvm-config... no
checking for llvm-config-3.8... no
checking for llvm-config-3.9... no
checking for llvm-config-4.0... llvm-config-4.0
checking LLVM version... 4.0.1: Good
configure: frama_clang: yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating ./Makefile.config
```

And here's the output of make (with environment variable VERBOSEMAKE=yes).

```
Generating   .Makefile.plugin.generated
Generating   intermediate AST
Generating   top/Frama_Clang.mli
Ocamldep     ./.depend
Ocamlc       intermediate_format.cmi
Ocamlc       intermediate_format_parser.cmi
Ocamlc       intermediate_format_parser.cmo
Ocamlc       frama_Clang_option.cmi
Ocamlc       frama_Clang_option.cmo
Ocamlc       fclang_datatype.cmi
Ocamlc       fclang_datatype.cmo
Ocamlc       cxx_utils.cmi
Ocamlc       cxx_utils.cmo
Ocamlc       mangling.cmi
Ocamlc       mangling.cmo
Ocamlc       convert_env.cmi
Ocamlc       convert_env.cmo
Ocamlc       convert_acsl.cmi
Ocamlc       convert_acsl.cmo
Ocamlc       generate_spec.cmi
Ocamlc       generate_spec.cmo
Ocamlc       class.cmi
Ocamlc       class.cmo
Ocamlc       convert.cmi
Ocamlc       convert.cmo
Ocamlc       convert_link.cmi
Ocamlc       convert_link.cmo
Ocamlc       frama_Clang_register.cmi
Ocamlc       frama_Clang_register.cmo
Ocamlc       Frama_Clang.cmi
Generating   top/Frama_Clang.cmi
Packing      top/Frama_Clang.cmo
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     intermediate_format_parser.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     frama_Clang_option.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     fclang_datatype.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     cxx_utils.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     mangling.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     convert_env.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     convert_acsl.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     generate_spec.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     class.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     convert.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     convert_link.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Ocamlopt     frama_Clang_register.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Packing      top/Frama_Clang.cmx
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
Packing      top/Frama_Clang.cmxs
findlib: [WARNING] Interface Frama_Clang.cmi occurs in several directories: /home/navarre/.opam/system/lib/frama-c/plugins, .
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/navarre/Downloads/frama-clang-0.0.3'
Compiling    Clang_utils.cpp
Compiling    intermediate_format.c
Compiling    ACSLComment.cpp
Compiling    ACSLLogicType.cpp
Compiling    ACSLTermOrPredicate.cpp
Compiling    ACSLLoopAnnotation.cpp
Compiling    ACSLStatementAnnotation.cpp
Compiling    ACSLGlobalAnnotation.cpp
Compiling    ACSLCodeAnnotation.cpp
Compiling    ACSLFunctionContract.cpp
Compiling    ACSLComponent.cpp
Compiling    ACSLLexer.cpp
Compiling    ACSLParser.cpp
Compiling    ACSLToken.cpp
Compiling    DescentParse.cpp
Compiling    RTTITable.cpp
Compiling    VisitTable.cpp
Compiling    ClangVisitor.cpp
Compiling    FramaCIRGen.cpp
Linking      bin/framaCIRGen
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/navarre/Downloads/frama-clang-0.0.3'
```

And here's the debug flag suggested in the comments:

```
navarre@navarre-t400:~/code/c$ frama-c max.cpp -fclang-msg-key clang
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing max.cpp (external front-end)
[fclang:clang] Clang command is framaCIRGen  -target i386-unknown-linux-gnu -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -std=c++11 -nostdinc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++ -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/libc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c --stop-annot-error -v  max.cpp -o /tmp/clang_ast8f7187ast
: CommandLine Error: Option 'asm-macro-max-nesting-depth' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
framaCIRGen  -target i386-unknown-linux-gnu -D__FC_MACHDEP_X86_32 -std=c++11 -nostdinc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/frama-clang/libc++ -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c/libc -I /home/navarre/.opam/system/share/frama-c --stop-annot-error -v  max.cpp -o /tmp/clang_ast8f7187ast[kernel] user error: Failed to parse C++ file. See Clang messages for more information
[kernel] user error: stopping on file "max.cpp" that has errors.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
[extlib] Debug: not removing file /tmp/clang_ast8f7187ast
```

Comment: I cannot help with the specific issue (which seems LLVM-related), but adding options such as `-fclang-debug 1` or `-fclang-msg-key clang` should give you more information, without requiring editing the source of `frama_Clang_register.ml`. It is possible however that you'll just get as much information as you have already got. And indeed, Frama-Clang does not do anything related to that asm option.

Comment: From what I can see, I'd say that the issue lies in the linking phase of framaCIRGen, in which presumably the translation unit registering asm-macro-max-nesting-depth appears twice for some reason. I suspect there's a mix between two versions of clang/llvm (especially considering your remark on issues with getting a suitable llvm installation). Could you post somewhere the result of `./configure` and of `VERBOSEMAKE=yes make` commands when compiling frama-clang?

Comment: @anol indeed, the way to go here is `-fclang-msg-key clang`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've given up for the time being. I will make another attempt this weekend, though, and let you guys know the output of the commands then.

Comment: I've posted the suggested outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was the age of the Ubuntu packages I was using. I was able to successfully install on another computer that ran 16.04 (mine had 14.04).

I have upgraded my computer and expect more success now.

Comment: Other users also find the same error, but debugging is not easy. In particular, we found out that compiling Clang from sources seems to work better than with distribution binaries (for instance, in Fedora 26 the same error as yours happens with the Clang 4.0 package, but not when compiling it from source). If you could give the exact version numbers (from before and after the bug), that would be helpful.